# Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "Android.Widget.EditText" в "string" C#

Tags: c#, преобразование

Вообщем есть такая проблема, т.е. я не могу преобразовать в String ту информацию, которую ввел в Plain Text. Ошибка дана в заголовке, может быть кто знает как можно решить сию проблему?

```
 EditText editText1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        EditText editText2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
        EditText editText3 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText3);
        bool ba = Int32.TryParse(editText1, out ebaa);
        bool bb = Int32.TryParse(editText2, out ebab);
        bool bc = Int32.TryParse(editText3, out ebac);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool ba = Int32.TryParse(editText1.Text, out ebaa);
```

и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. 
А почему при вводе "1" на месте editText1 у меня он булится как false?

Comment: @Daniil Если ответ решает Вашу проблему, отметьте его принятым, щелкнув по галочке слева. Вы смотрите куда-то не туда: вызов `Int32.TryParse("1", out ebaa);` должен возвращать `true`.

Comment: Я неправильно выразился. Когда я ввожу 1 в Plain Text , то мне выводит False